# How would i do a if statement to check if server has started

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to check if server started if it has then it will enter the client into the chatroom if not they cannot access the chatroom.

server

```
var app = require("http").createServer();

var io = require("socket.io")(application);




io.on('connection',function (socket) {
    console.log("A user has entered the server");

    socket.on("new client message",function (data) {
        console.log("Client message has been received: " + data);    

        io.emit("server message",data);
    })
});

app.listen(8084, function () {
    console.log("Server Started");
});
```

Comment: You don't need to worry about users entering the chatroom because they won't be able to connect to the chatroom until the server starts listening for incoming connections.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this callback:

```
app.listen(8084, function () {
    console.log("Server Started");
});
```

Tells you when the server has started.

---

You can also check the `.listening` property so see if the server is listening for new connections:

```
if (app.listening) {
    console.log("server is started");
}
```

---

But, you don't really need to check for it at all in your specific case because until the server is started and listening for incoming connections, you can't get anyone in the chatroom because they can't connect yet.

In addition, this:

```
var io = require("socket.io")(application);
```

needs to be:

```
var io = require("socket.io")(app);
```

---

It would also be clearer to people reading your code if the variable you named `app` was actually named `server` because that's what it is.  It's an http server instance.